# dar formato a fecha /Date()/ de AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

tengo el calendario y me genera un dato que me muestra de esta manera:

```
/Date(1513828800000)/
```

en la vista estoy obteniendo el date de:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtvalor" ng-model="datos.Fecha" placeholder="Fecha" />
```

trate de esta manera

```
 <td scope="row">{{datos.Fecha | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
```

tampoco así:

```
<td scope="row">{{ datos.Fecha | date : format : timezone}}</td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿conoces otra forma?.

Comment: Fecha realmente guarda un Date o es el tiempo en formato UNIX time?

Comment: lo obtengo de `<input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtvalor" ng-model="datos.Fecha" placeholder="Fecha" />`

Comment: Entonces es un string, necesitas un tipo date para darle formato con | date

Comment: no creo que sea un string, porque no almacenaria en mi DB que es de tipo ´date´

Answer (score 4, accepted):

su tienes otros prueban con la lista de numeros **1513828800000** y a ti te da **/Date(1513828800000)/** haz un substr :

```
{{datos.Fecha.substr(6,13) | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

siempre llegaran a esa cantidad de numeros "siempre se rellenan con **0** ejemplo: ***13/03/2017***"

Answer (score 1):

el filtro 'date' de angularJS parsea información tipo 'Long'. Por ende, asegúrate que:

- El dato obtenido de 'datos.Fecha' sea un valor de la fecha en milisegundos (Long), por ejemplo: 1288323623006 (Oct 28, 2010 10:40:23 PM). Que no sea indefinido o nulo.
- En la segunda manera que lo intentaste deberías tener definidos en el scope las variables de 'format' y 'timezone'. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  $scope.format = 'dd-MM-yyyy';
  $scope.timezone = '+0430;
  ```

Como ejemplo, te dejo lo siguiente (obtenido de [docs.angularjs.org](http://docs.angularjs.org)):

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 28, 2010 10:40:23 PM
```

Puedes guiarte con la documentación oficial de angularJS: [filterDate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

**ACTUALIZADO:**

Al parecer es un casteo realizado por Microsoft JSON, una solución podría ser esta:

```js
var fecha = "/Date(1224043200000)/";
console.log(new Date(parseInt(fecha.substr(6))));
```

Comment: encontre eso buscando, la cuestion es que no me manda solo numeros, me manda este dato `/Date(1513828800000)/`

Comment: Intenta:
`<td scope="row">{{new Date(datos.Fecha) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>`  y me cuentas.

Comment: me anula todo el angular, lo use y tengo una tabla con datos ya no me mostro nada de nada

Comment: Listo, al parecer sí es necesario el casteo con el substr, te dejo la fuente: [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Answer (score 1):

no se si sirva aun pero si alguien tiene el mismo problema lo solucioné como sigue:

```
<td scope="row">{{datos.Fecha | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
```